# Use previous column data for calculations while inserting data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a amortization table in the below format

```
StartNumber = 1000
TotalYears = 3
PerMonth =  StartNumber - (TotalYears*12)

          Month1       Month2                   Month3                 Month4..
Year1     StartNumber  Year1Month1-PerMonth    Year1Month2-PerMonth
Year2      
Year3
Year4
....
```

What this shows is that based on the number of years I will construct the year rows and then I will start with the total amount in the Year1Month1 and then For 
Year1Month2 I will deduct the Previous Column data with the PerMonth variable.

I was thinking of creating a temp table and processing data to fill it

```
Declare @Years int
Set @Years = 3

Declare @TotalUnrecoveredDollar decimal(8,3)
Set @TotalUnrecoveredDollar = 10000.3

Declare @UnrecoveredDollarPerMonth decimal(8,3)
Set @UnrecoveredDollarPerMonth = @TotalUnrecoveredDollar - (@Years * 12)

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AmortizationTable') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #AmortizationTable
  END

  CREATE TABLE #AmortizationTable
  (
    Month1 decimal(10,3),
    Month2 decimal(10,3),
    Month3 decimal(10,3),
    Month4 decimal(10,3),
    Month5 decimal(10,3),
    Month6 decimal(10,3),
    Month7 decimal(10,3),
    Month8 decimal(10,3),
    Month9 decimal(10,3),
    Month10 decimal(10,3),
    Month11 decimal(10,3),
    Month12 decimal(10,3)
  )
```

My question is that while inserting data in a table is it possible to use previous cell data for calculation while starting the first cell with some data.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Not in SQL Server 2008

Comment: @GordonLinoff My Bad. btw if you have chance please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799428/mysql-empty-table-returns-true-when-queried-using-a-left-join  I could reproduce the wrong behaviour in rextester.

Comment: Calculating on the fly is a bit difficult without recursion, but your calculation just seems to be a flat number (e.g. cell X will be startnumber - (x-1)*permonth) so this doesn't seem like a hard thing to do.

Comment: Actually you can, by using the "CROSS APPLY ( VALUES" method. I'll try to post an example.

Comment: Example... DECLARE @SomeValue INT = 5;

SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 ( VALUES (22) ) c1 (Col_1)
 CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (c1.Col_1 * @SomeValue) ) c2 (Col_2)
 CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (c2.Col_2 * @SomeValue) ) c3 (Col_3)
 CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (c3.Col_3 * @SomeValue) ) c4 (Col_4)
 CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (c4.Col_4 * @SomeValue) ) c5 (Col_5);

Comment: Tables are not spreadsheets, despite their superficial resemblance. A spreadsheet may be a better tool to pick for this job. Also, your temp table is broken - tables have no inherent order and so you have no means of knowing which rows apply to which year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understand , you have a (@startnumber variable , @PerMonth variable) and all fields depends on them, so you can make something like

```
insert into AmortizationTable(Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5
, Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12)

select @StartNumber , @StartNumber-@PerMonth, @StartNumber-(@PerMonth*2),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*3),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*4),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*5)
,@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*6),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*7),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*8),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*9),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*10),@StartNumber-(@PerMonth*11)
```